# ASP.NET MVC - The controller for path '/non' was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, overlay

I use the jQuery Tools Overlay plugin and I have this code here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var overlayElem;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("a[rel]").live('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                overlayElem = $(this);

                $(this).overlay({
                    mask: '#3B5872',
                    effect: 'apple',
                    api: true,
                    load: true,
                    onBeforeLoad: function () {
                        var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
                        wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
                    }
                });
            });

            var triggers = $(".modalInput").overlay({
                mask: {
                    color: '#ebecff',
                    loadSpeed: 200,
                    opacity: 0.9,
                    top: '50%',
                    api: true
                },
                closeOnClick: false
            });


            var buttons = $("#yesno button").click(function (e) {
                var yes = buttons.index(this) === 0;
                if (yes) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: overlayElem.attr('href'),
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#gridcontainer").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        function ajaxFormRequest(form, callback, format) {
            $.ajax({
                url: form.action,
                type: form.method,
                dataType: format,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: callback
            });
        }

        function update_grid(result) {
            overlayElem.overlay().close();
            $("#gridcontainer").html(result);
        }

    </script>
```

I found out that everytime I use the delete confirmation dialog this error is thrown.

I do not have any code that has a link to **"/non"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its kinda like 'null' or 'undefined' because js cant find the image that you have defined as the background for the overlay.

I just had this, and all i had to do what specify a background image in the CSS like this:

```
#overlay {background: #fff url(images/white.png);}
```

hope that helps!

Comment: I will try this sometimes later :) Great info!